# removeObserver crashing my app even though appears to be balanced with addObserver

Tags: ios, key-value-observing, addobserver

So I have a class, `CustomCell : UITableViewCell` with a single `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` method, called in `-awakeFromNib`, and a single `removeObserver:forKeyPath:context:` method, called in `-dealloc`.

CustomCell.m

```
static void * const MyClassKVOContext = (void*)&MyClassKVOContext; // unique context

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self registerAsLocationListener];
}


-(void)registerAsLocationListener
{
    if ([self.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"locationcell1"])
    {
        [[RA_LocationSingleton locationSingleton]
              addObserver:self
               forKeyPath:@"currentLocation"
                  options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                  context:MyClassKVOContext];

        NSLog(@"Registered for currentLocation");
        NSLog(@"self.description: %@", [self description]);
    }
}


-(void)dealloc
{
    if ([self.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"locationcell1"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Attempting to deregister");
        NSlog(@"self.description: %@", [self description]);

        [self removeObserver:self
               forKeyPath:@"currentLocation"
                  context:MyClassKVOContext];
    }

    // [super dealloc]; called automatically, using ARC
}
```

I get the following log, after loading the view with these cells, then backing out again (triggering the dealloc)

```
// load view
2014-09-01 14:27:33.704 Rally[2931:60b] Registered for currentLocation
2014-09-01 14:27:33.705 Rally[2931:60b] self.description: <CustomCell: 0x9afa570; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 44); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x9afa710>>

// exit from view
2014-09-01 14:27:40.867 Rally[2931:60b] Attempting to deregister
2014-09-01 14:27:40.868 Rally[2931:60b] self.description: <CustomCell: 0x9afa570; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 231; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x9afa710>>
2014-09-01 14:27:40.870 Rally[2931:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'Cannot remove an observer <CustomCell 0x9afa570> for the key path "currentLocation" from <CustomCell 0x9afa570> because it is not registered as an observer.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x026761e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x023f58e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x02675fbb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
3   Foundation                          0x0204346d -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverRegistration) _removeObserver:forProperty:] + 538
4   Foundation                          0x020431f4 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverRegistration) removeObserver:forKeyPath:] + 105
5   Foundation                          0x02043118 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverRegistration) removeObserver:forKeyPath:context:] + 172
6   Rally                               0x00005ac1 -[CustomCell dealloc] + 353
7   UIKit                               0x01107b94 -[UIView release] + 89
8   CoreFoundation                      0x025f7bf0 CFRelease + 272
9   CoreFoundation                      0x0261716e -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 142
10  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02406692 _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb + 268
11  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02405e81 objc_release + 49
12  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02406ce7 _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_119AutoreleasePoolPage3popEPv + 537
13  CoreFoundation                      0x02617878 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 24
14  CoreFoundation                      0x0261c5d3 __CFRunLoopRun + 1971
15  CoreFoundation                      0x0261b9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
16  CoreFoundation                      0x0261b7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
17  GraphicsServices                    0x036f85ee GSEventRunModal + 192
18  GraphicsServices                    0x036f842b GSEventRun + 104
19  UIKit                               0x010b5f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
20  Rally                               0x00006a6d main + 141
21  libdyld.dylib                       0x02ef6701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I've double-checked (ctrl+f) that nowhere else are these methods called. So it seems that for any instance, there is precisely one `addObserver` (with unique context) and precisely one `removeObserver` (with that context)

Comment: Doesn't iOS automatically remove observers? If so, it might have already been removed when `dealloc` was called...

Comment: Just spotted my typo. I was sending removeObserver to self, but should have sent it to [RA_LocationSingleton locationSingleton]

Comment: @jjv360 - I don't believe so. I was getting another type of crash before I implemented the removeObserver

Comment: Oh, maybe that's only for `NSNotificationCenter` observers...

Comment: The `NSNotificationCenter` removes the observers automatically only if the app is targeted to iOS 9+ and you add the observer with `addObserver:selector:name:object:`. See the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotificationcenter/1407263-removeobserver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies all

Have just spotted my typo:

```
[self removeObserver:self
           forKeyPath:@"currentLocation"
              context:MyClassKVOContext];
```

should be

```
[[RA_LocationSingleton locationSingleton] removeObserver:self
                                              forKeyPath:@"currentLocation"
                                                 context:MyClassKVOContext];
```